# how to number of rows affected by delete in sybase

Tags: sybase

There is requirement that I want rows affected by delete operation in sybase any one if know please do let me know.

There is not sufficient documentation for sybase as I see.

Comment: What did you try?  What exactly you are trying to achieve?  You did no give us enough details.

Comment: I am doing clean up activity on certain table if data is older than seven days. If the data is odler than 7 days I am just deleting the data and its working fine
Now I need to know how many rows got deleted  for that purpose I want delete from table gives me number of rows got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

According to : https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3732742 did you checked this?

> master.monProcessStatement.RowsAffected